# Sending Latitude and Longitude double values to MVC Controller but getting NULL values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I have hard coded the latitude and longitude values but still i'm getting null values in controller, I have tried many solutions but couldn't get it to work. I think there is a mismatch between my javascript object "mydata" and my MVC object Table.

Javascript Code

```js
<script>
map.setContextMenu({
                control: 'map',
                options: [{
                    title: 'Click to add marker',
                    name: 'add_marker',
                    action: function (e) {
                        $("#markerform").show();
                        var latitude = 31.555;
                        var longitude = 74.333;
                        var m = $('#m').val();
                        var n = $('#n').val();
                        var o = $('#o').val();
                        var ad = $('#ad').val();
                        var ph = $('#ph').val();
                        var w = $('#w').val();
                        var fb = $('#fb').val();
                        var l = "RAO";

                        var mydata = {
                            lat: latitude,
                            lng: longitude,
                            marker: m,
                            name: n,
                            offer: o,
                            address: ad,
                            phn: ph,
                            website: w,
                            fbpage: fb,
                            logo: l
                        };
                        function SaveMarker() {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: mydata,
                                url: "/Home/AddMarker",
                                // dataType: 'json',
                                // data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                success: function () {
                                    alert('suc');
                                },
                                error: function (args) {
                                    alert('error');
                                }
                            });
                     }
                    }
                }
                ]
            });
</script>
```

In controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMarker(Table t){

       //Some Code
        return View("../Home/Index");
}
```

My Table Class

```
 public partial class Table
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> lat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> lng { get; set; }
    public string marker { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string offer { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phn { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string fbpage { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Chris Pratt, i finally found the solution. i was calling the function SaveMarker from a form that is why the function was not reading the latitude and longitude values. Now i am getting the lat lng values in a separate funtion using a separate ajax call, everything is working smoothly now :).

Answer (score 0):

Don't stringify your JSON data. You're posting a string at that point, not JSON or a set of name-value pairs. MVC attempts to bind the string itself as `Table` and of course fails, because there's no conversion from `string` to your `Table` class. Instead, just pass `data` itself as the `data` param for your AJAX request. That also assumes that the JavaScript object represented by `data` mirrors your C# `Table` class. Otherwise, you'll still have issues with binding. In other words, if your `Table` class has a property `Latitude`, then your JavaScript object would need to have a member named `Latitude` or `latitude` (casing doesn't matter).

Comment: i haven't stringify my data, as u can see it is already commented, but i will try to pass data as param in my ajax request.

Comment: i have tried to pass data as param but im still getting null values for latitude, longitude and logo. it seems like only those var that i have hard coded are giving null values.